# open full screen terminal app in another terminal

Tags: c, file-descriptor, tty

As an educational project, am I trying to write a simple terminal text editor. Below is a minimal example of my editor. My editor works fine when opening in the same terminal from which the program was run, however I would like to display the editor in a second terminal, leaving the original one free to print logging messages to. In the example below, the editor sucessfully opens in the second terminal, and the logging message about the number of rows and columns is printed in the original terminal. However, I can't work out how to get the editor to receive input from the second terminal, currently I need to close it by pressing ctrl+q in the orginal terminal. How can I get the editor to receive input from the second terminal?
I am compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -g c_programs/open_alt_screen_in_other_term.c` and running with `./a.out -tty /dev/pts/0`

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ENTER_ALT_SCREEN "\033[?1049h"
#define EXIT_ALT_SCREEN "\033[?1049l"
#define MOVE_CURSOR_HOME "\033[H"
#define CTRL_KEY(k) ((k)&0x1f)

int UI_OUTPUT_FILENO = STDOUT_FILENO;
int UI_INPUT_FILENO = STDIN_FILENO;

struct termios orig_termios;

void disable_raw_mode();
void enable_raw_mode() {
  tcgetattr(UI_INPUT_FILENO, &orig_termios);
  atexit(disable_raw_mode);

  struct termios raw = orig_termios;
  raw.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | ICRNL);
  raw.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
  raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
  raw.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | INPCK | ISTRIP);
  raw.c_cflag |= (CS8);
  tcsetattr(UI_INPUT_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw);
}
void disable_raw_mode() {
  tcsetattr(UI_INPUT_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &orig_termios);
  write(UI_OUTPUT_FILENO, EXIT_ALT_SCREEN, 8);
}
int getWindowSize(int *rows, int *cols) {
  struct winsize ws;
  if (ioctl(UI_OUTPUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws) == -1 || ws.ws_col == 0) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    *cols = ws.ws_col;
    *rows = ws.ws_row;
    return 0;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE *lfp = NULL;
  for (int a = 1; a < argc; a++) {
    if (strcmp(argv[a], "-tty") == 0) {
      lfp = fopen(argv[a + 1], "w");
      UI_OUTPUT_FILENO = fileno(lfp);
      // UI_INPUT_FILENO = UI_OUTPUT_FILENO;
    }
  }

  enable_raw_mode();
  write(UI_OUTPUT_FILENO, ENTER_ALT_SCREEN, 8);
  write(UI_OUTPUT_FILENO, MOVE_CURSOR_HOME, 3);

  int nrows, ncols;
  if (getWindowSize(&nrows, &ncols) == -1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
  // print logging to original terminal
  printf("rows: %d, cols: %d\n", nrows, ncols);

  char seq[10] = {0};

  while (read(UI_INPUT_FILENO, &seq, 10) != 0) {
    if (seq[0] == CTRL_KEY('q')) {
      break;
    } else if (strlen(seq) == 1) {
      write(UI_OUTPUT_FILENO, seq, 1);
    }

    for (size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) seq[j] = '\0';
  }

  // if I clode lfp, the other terminal doesn't exit alt screen
  // fclose(lfp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But why do you want to open it in _the second_ terminal? Why not open in the current, like other editors? `UI_OUTPUT_FILENO = fileno(lfp);` don't use `fopen` at all, just `open` it. `How can I get the editor to receive input from the second terminal?` So uncomment `// UI_INPUT_FILENO = UI_OUTPUT_FILENO;`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I want to open it in a second terminal so that I can keep the original terminal for logging messages during use of the editor, for debugging purposes.

Comment: That's odd, sounds like not something users would expect. I suggest: open it in current terminal and log messages to a file. Just like `vim -V9/tmp/logfile.log` would do. Then use `tail -F /tmp/logfile.log` to inspect messages in another terminal.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes it wouldn't be something users expect, but there won't be any users since this is just an educational project for myself. But thanks for the idea of writing to a log file, that will help solve my immediate need to log some debug info, but I would also like to learn how to display the editor in a second terminal, for my own learning purposes. It seems like it should be possible, and I just don't know how to get the stdin file descriptor for the second terminal.